# PHP adding days to a date in a new variable changes the other

Tags: php

I have a variable `invoiceDate`, which is a `datetime` type. I calculate the `dueDate` by adding 14 days to the `invoiceDate` with the following:

```
private $invoiceDate; // this is any datetime. 
private $dueDate;

public function calculateDueDate(){
    $due = date_add($this->invoiceDate, new \DateInterval('P14D'))  ;
    return $due;
}

public function getInvoiceDate()
{
    return $this->invoiceDate;
}

public function getDueDate()
{
    $this->dueDate = $this->calculateDueDate();
    return $this->dueDate;
}
```

What I don't get is that when I use the method `getDueDate()` or `getInvoiceDate()` I always get the original `invoiceDate` plus 14 days, on both methods. Why is the original date affected and what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Have you read this - http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php#refsect1-datetime.add-parameters?

Comment: @u_mulder, yes I did and the calculating works. However, I wish to end up with 2 dates, the original and the calculated one. The original also changes and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because such behaviour is described in the link provided.

Comment: @u_mulder, I did not understand it would change the original object, but I thank you for explaining this to me and giving me the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open [`date_add`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php#refsect1-datetime.add-parameters) manual and see that first argument of `date_add` is:

> A `DateTime` object returned by `date_create()`. The function **modifies this object**.

So, you need to modify **another object**, for example, a clone:

```
public function calculateDueDate(){
    $due = date_add(
        clone $this->invoiceDate, 
        new \DateInterval('P14D')
    );
    return $due;
}
```